# Is it considered a bad coding practice to use, at the same time, css commands at the .css file and inline css commands at the .html file?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web design and I'm realizing that it's possible to use the `html` just for the page structure and the `css` for the page design. Is it ok to use inline commands like `style="display: block"` or `style="background-image: url(image.com)`, in the `html` file? Or is it considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS within a `<style>` tag or importing in from a `.css` file provides all of your selectors with a [specificity range](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) that will be overridden by any CSS provided through the `style` attribute.

As a general rule you want to try to keep as much CSS as possible within your `.css` files or `<style>` tags.

I try to keep over 90% of all CSS in files and I only put css into the `style` attribute when I am changing specific values that are difficult to code in a CSS file. Like rotation angle, top and left positions of things that are drug around the screen, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to insert css in the css file, because as a developer, you'll have a lot of code in your html file and if you add inline css then it could get messy. Adding css in the css file is easier to read and easier to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping all your css inside a .css file will give you much cleaner html file and enable you to make changes to your styling much easier as everything is in one place.

There will be times where it is much easier to add an inline style attribute to an element but even this can be avoided with couple extra lines of code on the css side to make your html look as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that anyway that helps you achieve your style goal is ok to use as long as it works for you.

That said, I usually try to keep all the styles that affect the site in general in a .css file and link it in globally to the site pages.

In some cases, there may be a page or two that need styles that are not needed by the rest of the site, therefore I add the `<style>` tag with the style rules in those few pages.

When an inline element in the html needs a special distinction using a style not defined in the locations mentioned above, I added it there inline with the style attribute. In these cases I have to make a note that, those elements will not change when the other css changes throughout the site.

Of course there are other things like the !important directive, etc, that can affect or override the inline style.

As mention by others in this post, there are other considerations to take into account, on where to place your css for individual reasons deemed by the designer.